# SQL query: WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

My table `rating` is having the following structure:

`RATING (INT 'id', INT 'stars') primary key 'id';`

It is already known that `stars` can have value from 1 to 5 only.

Below are some possible content of my table:

**Sample Table1:**

```
ID  Stars
--  -----
1   5
2   4
3   4
4   4
5   5
6   4
7   4
```

**Sample Table2:**

```
ID  Stars
--  -----
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   2
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   2
9   1
```

I am querying my table with the following query:

```
SELECT stars, count(stars) as count
FROM rating
GROUP BY stars
ORDER BY stars desc;
```

**Sample Table1 Output:**

```
stars  count
-----  -----
5      2
4      5
```

**Sample Table2 Output:**

```
stars  count
-----  -----
3      1
2      3
1      5
```

**My Problem:**
I want such a query where the output is shown **ZERO** for the value which is not present in the table i.e.

For Sample table1 I want output like:

```
stars  count
-----  -----
5      2
4      5
3      0
2      0
1      0
```

For Sample Table2 I want output like:

```
stars  count
-----  -----
5      0
4      0
3      1
2      3
1      5
```

Please note that it is known that `stars` can have only values from 1 to 5.

---

The query I am trying is (not working correctly):

```
SELECT stars, count(stars) as count
FROM rating
WHERE stars in (1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY stars
ORDER BY stars desc;
```

Is the problem with the where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select s.stars, count(r.stars) as count
from
(
  select 1 as stars
  union all select 2
  union all select 3
  union all select 4
  union all select 5
) s
left join rating r on s.stars = r.stars
group by s.stars
order by s.stars desc
```

Something like this

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.id, count(r.stars) as starcount
FROM rating r
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 as id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) s
  ON (s.id = r.stars)
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.id desc;
```

Comment: Hi Johan: It is showing the following wrong output. `Stars: 5,4,null,null,null` and `Count: 2,5,0,0,0`

Comment: @iSumitG, Make sure you are doing `select s.id ...` **not** `select r.stars, ....`